# How to control css3 animation rotate direction

Tags: animation, css, transform, rotation, direction

I want rotate a element with css3 animation and transform property,which from  20 degree to -20 degree

```
@-moz-keyframes oneRotate{
    0%{
        -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
    }
    100%{
        -moz-transform:rotate(-20deg);
    }
}

.oneRotate
{
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

   -moz-animation-name:oneRotate;
   -moz-animation-duration:2s;
   -moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
   -moz-animation-delay:0s;
   -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
   -moz-animation-direction:normal;
}
```

the rotate order is 20 -> 0 -> -20... is anti-clockwise

but I want the order is 20 -> 90 -> 180 -> ...is clockwise

what can I do to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the 100% rotation angle to 340 degrees. It's the same angle as -20 degrees since -20 + 360 = 340, but it'll rotate in the opposite direction since 340 > 20 but -20 < 20.

Comment: but when I want the start angle is 80 degree and the end is 20 degree,with clockwise direction?

Comment: Then you add 360 to 20 to get 380 degrees and set that as the end. The rule is that if the end is greater than the start, it'll rotate clockwise; if the end is less than the start, it's counterclockwise.

Comment: rotate3d doesn't follows this rule apparently. Is this correct or is it a bug?